# Apple push notification on multiple devices

Tags: ios

How to send push notification on multiple devices using tokenId list.

i am able to get the token id of device where app is installed. but problem is how to send this token id to server side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a server-side API call (web service method or something similar) that accepts token id from the devices. The server then connects with APN server to authenticate and send out notifications as JSON payload.